# Should one or two tables be used for 'for sale/wanted' listings? Each status requires slightly different attributes

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm working on a web application for school using laravel. Users will input books they have for trade and also select books that they want. The site will notify a user when a book they are looking for was posted by somebody else. Currently, I have one table with a fortrade/wanted column and could just run queries based off the value of that attribute. However, I'm starting to wonder if it would make things easier to have separate tables for this. While many columns would be shared, there are currently columns only used by one of the statuses. For example, a book listed for trade will contain the book title, condition, and the user's location. While the books wanted list only needs the userid and the isbn for the book, so there would be a lot of null values. Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Updated the title. Hopefully it's more inline with the rules now.

Comment: Not really. This is a code site. There are other places for other types of questions

Comment: The comment was regarding the post and not just the title. Recommendations for problems can be opinionated and also can change even for minor details. Why don't you try to design a solution one way and see if that works and then compare with the other way and see which one works better for your use cases.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was actually looking for some subjective advice from anybody with more experience. So opinions were welcome. I guess I misunderstood the scope of acceptable questions for this site. I'll try to post this on a beginner's subreddit or something more novice-friendly. Thanks for the input.